# kvoptions declare local complementary options

Tags: kvoptions

Given the following declarations in a `tst` package using `kvoptions`

```
\ProvidesPackage{tst}
 ...
\DeclareBoolOption{abc}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{cba}{abc}
```

Which is the correct way of declaring both options as local:
    `\DeclareLocalOptions{abc}`
or
    `\DeclareLocalOptions{abc,cba}`
since they both share the same internal representation (flag)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Local" in `\DeclareLocalOptions` does refer to the place, where options are recognized, e.g. `\usepackage`. But such "local" options are *not* recognized, if specified as global option in `\documentclass`.

Therefore this meaning of "local" does not refer to the implementation of the option, both options need to be specified in `\DeclareLocalOptions`, if both should not be recognized as global option:

```
\ProvidesPackage{tst}
...
\DeclareBoolOption{abc}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{cba}{abc}
\DeclareLocalOptions{abc, cba}
```